# HandlerInterceptorAdapter doesn't run on login with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, interceptor

My interceptor run in all request except on login.

Interceptor:

```
public class MultitenantHandler extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

        private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MultitenantHandler.class);

        @Override
        public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, Object handler){

            String origin = req.getHeader("Origin");
            log.debug("Origin: "+origin);

            if (origin == null) {
                origin = "localhost";
            }

            int indexDot = origin.indexOf(".");
            int indexDash = origin.indexOf("://") + 3;

            String tenant = "";

            if (indexDot == -1) {
                tenant = "experter";
                log.warn("Using default tenant");
                TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(tenant);

            } else {
                tenant = origin.substring(indexDash, indexDot);
                log.info("Using tenant: " + tenant);
                TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(tenant);
            }

            return true;

        }
}
```

On `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` I register this way:

```
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new MultitenantHandler());
    }
```

It's my security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Profile({"development", "demo", "default"})
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private RESTLogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private JWTAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private JWTAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private StatelessAuthenticationFilter statelessAuthFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);

        http.formLogin().permitAll()
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler);

        http.logout().permitAll()
                .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler);

        http.addFilterBefore(statelessAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login/changePassword").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/image").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/social/login/facebook").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER");

        log.info("Configuration of http complete.");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
```

When I request `/login` the interceptor doesn't run, in other request even not logged the interceptor work normally.

I need to execute the interceptor before any request, because I need to set the database according url request.

If you need more information, please, tell me that I can post here.

Comment: Spring Security is implemented using filters, which execute before the `DispatcherServlet` and any controllers/handlers you have. So of course it will not run. Implement it with a filter instead of a `HandlerInterceptor`.

Comment: Thanks your response @M.Deinum. But as I soon as I know the filter don't change the behavior of this method. According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/35856496/2463802 "Filter is well-suited for request content and view content handling, like multipart forms and GZIP compression. This typically shows when one needs to map the filter to certain content types (e.g. images), or to all requests."

Comment: Your understanding of filters is flawed. What you want to achieve you cannot achieve with a handler interceptor you must use a filter. A filter can do a lot more then a `Handlerinterceptor` and as mentioned before Spring Security is implemented using filters, and as such a `HandlerInterceptor` simply isn't an option.

Comment: Great! I understood the working and could solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same problem I solved this problem using filter as @M.Deinum sugested. I used the same filter that I use to validate the authentication token.