# Spring Security: External authentication and internal authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-rest

I have a REST service which relies on an external system for authenticating the token but needs to do authorization(API level access using like @Secured) by itself.

Requirement:

1. UI generates the token using an external system.
2. UI makes REST calls with the token to my service.
3. My service validates the token using the external system but authentication for API calls is done by my service

One possible solution was to do this using a filter:

1. UI generates the token using an external system.
2. UI makes REST calls with the token to my service.
3. My service has a filter that invokes the external system with the token.
4. The external system for valid token sends back the user details.
5. My service on successful call set's the SecurityContextHolder like

   SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new 
   AuthorizedUser("test", Arrays.asList(new 
   SimpleGrantedAuthority("test_role")), "test",null));

Is there any other way this can be achieved?

Comment: Are you trying to use something like facebook or google auth?

Comment: @uğurtaş Nops. This is just another microservice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for proposals on your architecture then you may save an extra call to an "external system" by changing step one and other steps:

1. UI generates the token using an external system.

   1.1. The external system saves user details inside some in-memory key-value database (like Redis).

...

3. My service has a filter that fetches user details from Redis using token.

It makes sense if you want to protect the "external system" from being spammed by multiple calls from your filter.

If you are looking for implementation hints, then calling `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication()` when your code verified authentication and completed authorization seems fine for me.

Maybe it is a better idea to use `@javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed` instead of `@Secured` (works the same way but the name is more obvious).

And sometimes you may like to use `org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` instead of a filter, see this for example: [Difference between Interceptor and Filter in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856454/difference-between-interceptor-and-filter-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: @JDev Was my answer useful to you?