# Earliest point to encrypt json payload in spring mvc application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, obfuscation, masking, spring-logback

I have an spring boot application serving restful api's.

I'd like to make sure that certain fields are masked / encrypted at the earliest possible time so that they are not shown in clear text in the application log ... via logback.

Is there an entry point / filter / sprint aspect I can implement so a to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

As cearly explained in [Ali Dehghani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1393484/ali-dehghani)'s Answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856454/difference-between-interceptor-and-filter-in-spring-mvc) the best place to do what you want to, is in a Response filter. So you have to write a class that implements the **Filter** interface and you *filter* your response in the **doFilter** method.

```
@Component
public class YourResponseFilter implements Filter {
 
  @Override
  public void doFilter(
    ServletRequest request, 
    ServletResponse response, 
    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    ...
    // do your work there
  }
}
```

You may or may not use the annotate your filter with *@Component*, depending in the fact if you want to filter all your reponses or not.
If you need more help let me know.