# Calculate All Spring Controller Execution time

Tags: java, spring, time, controller, spring-aop

How to calculate Spring Controller Execution time for All spring Controller?
Let's say I have 200 Spring REST Controller in my Application, how can I  calculate execution time for each controller and save that time in Database?

Answer (score 1):

Write a Servlet [`HttpFilter`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpFilter.html) or a Spring MVC [`HandlerInterceptor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html).

For `HandlerInterceptor`, see [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor).

See also [Difference between Interceptor and Filter in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35856454/5221149).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Aspect](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html) to add this behaviour to your application.

```
@Aspect 
@Component
@Slf4j
public class RequestLogAspect {

  @Autowired DurationRepository repo;
  ... 
  
  @Around("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping) 
           && execution(public * *(..))"
  )
  public Object log(final ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {

    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
            .currentRequestAttributes())
            .getRequest();
  
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Object value;

    try {
        value = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        throw throwable;
    } finally {
        long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

        log.info("{} {} from {} took {} ms",
                request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURI(),
                request.getRemoteAddr(), duration);
        // use repo and the information above to persist data
    }

    return value;
  }
}
```

Source from [this tutorial](https://niels.nu/blog/2017/spring-boot-aop.html).