# Try in JAVA Spring, @AutoWired Filter service but throws NPE

Tags: java, spring, filter, redis, dao

My project is using spring framework to process http request and response.
I have a request that replace some parameters with the value from the redis or database depend on one of the parameters.

I survey most of related cases are used filter to reach the purpose.

For example, there are two parameters customerName:abc, isNickName:true of api.
And I try to implement a class which extends OncePerRequestFilter class like belows.

```
@Component("myFilter")
public class ConvertNickNameToRealNameFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{

  @AutoWired
  private CustomerDao customerDao;

  @AutoWired
  private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

  protected abstract void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

    ...
    If (isNickName){
      customerName = getRealName(customerName); 
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    ...

  }

  // repo = repository = redis
  // dao = database
  public String getRealName(String nickName){
    String realName = customerRepository.getRealName(nickName);
    if(realName == null) {
      Customer c = customerDao.findByNickName(nickName);
      if(c != null){
        customerRepository.set(nickName, c.getRealName());
        return (c == null) ? "" : c.getRealName();
      }
    }else{
      return realName;
    }
  }
}
```

in web.xml

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I tried use @AutoWired annotation to inject the dao and repo but failed.
How to handle dao and repo are null?
Any hint would be welcome and have sample code would be perfect.

Thank you for the help.

---

Finally, I found a way to make it work which uses DelegatingFilterProxy in filter-class instead of Class itself.

Can see the code above which is the main block.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons for why its null. I would check the following:

1. Autowiring in spring happens only if the class itself (ConvertNickNameToRealNameFilter) is managed by spring. I do see that you've put a "Component" on it, but the code like `chain.doFilter` might hint that you're actually using java servlet's filtering technology that is not integrated with spring MVC (in fact spring MVC is built on top of low-level servlets).
2. It's possible that the class is not put in a package that isn't handled by "component scanning process" of spring - so that spring doesn't load it, does the code come into it at all?
3. If everything is managed by spring, make sure that there the repositories and the filter are not handled in different application context

All in all, I suggest using Spring mvc interceptors as opposed to plain filters. These are integrated with Spring MVC. [See this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856454/difference-between-interceptor-and-filter-in-spring-mvc#:%7E:text=As%20I%20understood%20from%20docs,but%20after%20Controller%20rendered%20response.) for differences between them

Comment: Hi Mark,Thank you your generous answer. 1. Yes, the filter is selvet based, and I want to integrate it to spring MVC. And finally, I try use DelegatingFilterProxy to implement it. 2. all code come into one project. 3. only one application context, and seems like previous config is not applied in the spring context. And I'd to read the infomation you shared.