# How can I add few auth steps in spring boot + spring security?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, filter, spring-security, interceptor

I have a spring boot application with spring security. It works fine.

1. I call HTTP://localhost:8080/test request
2. `AuthenticationProvider` catches this request and authenticates the user.
3. `MyController` starts working

Now I need to add license checking to this chain.

1. I call HTTP://localhost:8080/test request
2. `AuthenticationProvider` catches this request and authenticates the user.
3. **Somebody** checks the license and redirect to the next step or returns an exception
4. if the 3-th step is a success - `MyController` starts working

I need to understand who is **Somebody** on 3-th step - Interceptor, Filter, or something else?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856454/difference-between-interceptor-and-filter-in-spring-mvc#:~:text=As%20I%20understood%20from%20docs,but%20after%20Controller%20rendered%20response. Filter should be your to go here

Answer (score 0):

I would create a CustomAuthenticationProvider that is using the underlying default functionality for authentication and additionally does your licence checking.